# Rstudio fatal error with partion in multidplyr

Tags: r, rstudio, multidplyr

I am having issues with Rstudio keeps crashing when I am trying to partition my data. I managed to reproduce the same problem using the nycflights13 data is being used in the vignette of multidplyr.

This works

```
library(multidplyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

cluster <- new_cluster(4)

library(nycflights13)

flight_dest <- flights %>% partition(cluster)
```

But when I do

```
cluster <- new_cluster(2) ## or other numbers for istance 6

flight_dest <- flights %>% partition(cluster)
```

It crashes and I get the following message

> R Session Aborted
>
> R encountered a fatal error
>
> The session was terminated

I am using Rstudio (1.2.5033) and R version 3.6.2

When I run in inside R it does work.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10.